# making my rawinput case insensitive

Tags: python-2.7, search, case-insensitive, raw-input

Im scraping websites for hrefs I have used .lower() and thats fine but now when i add new sites i have notice some have Upper and lower case in the hrefs.

How can i make it when the user input finds matches of links with both.

example a search for 'rangers' would show all Rangers,rangers,rAnGeRs and so on.

> user_input   = raw_input ("Search for Team = ")
>
> headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' } req =
>   urllib2.Request("http://wizhdsports.com/sports/Football.html", None,
>   headers) resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,
>   from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))
>
> links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(user_input)) if len(links)
>   == 0:
>       print "Wizhdsports.com Have No Streams Available" else:
>       for link in links: 
>           print (link['href'])

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Regular Expressions to match the user input, you can use the `re.IGNORECASE` flag to `re.compile` which will perform a case-insensitive match.

your original code example updated:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

user_input = raw_input ("Search for Team = ")

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
req = urllib2.Request("http://wizhdsports.com/sports/Football.html", None, headers)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)

# fix UserWarning that parser not explicitly specified with bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser", from_encoding=resp.info().getparam('charset'))

links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(user_input, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
if len(links) == 0:
    print "Wizhdsports.com Have No Streams Available"
else:
    for link in links:
        print (link['href'])
```